# Brackets determining what gets pushed onto array

Tags: javascript

Working to find the multiples of an integer up to a limit. Found that the use of brackets determines what gets  pushed to the array.

```
//This will return one integer multiple to the array
function findMultiples(integer, limit) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = integer; i <= limit; i += integer) {
        arr.push(i)
        return arr
    }
}

//This will return all the integer multiples to the array
function findMultiples(integer, limit) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = integer; i <= limit; i += integer) arr.push(i)
    return arr
}
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: This is how curly brackets work. I am sorry but I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in what is "scoped" inside the for loop. JS is whitespace independent so spacing does not affect the scope, what affects it are the brackets. Basically when you donot but the brackets of a loop it runs until the next command. So your second function is equivalent to

```js
function findMultiples(integer, limit) {

  let arr = [];
  for(let i = integer; i <= limit; i += integer ) {
     arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
    
}
```

The code above states that all elements would be pushed to array and then the array will be returned however in your first function the array is instantly returned after the first iteration of the loop so the loop does not execute any further.

Comment: just adding to the above answer, the first function will return immediately after the first arr.push(i).. that's why it only return one integer